# Forcing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException?

Tags: java, sockets, indexoutofboundsexception

It's for testing purposes, as I'm reading a book, and I coudn't find the Program mentioned in the exercise. I need to create an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, to possibly debug and analyze it.

Should be something like a BufferOverFlow as e.g. in C, maybe not a good example with Java.

The Program seems to execute what is assigned from one Array to another Array, through a Server.

On the client, I have a String-Array with 10 as limited content. The Program from the Server put more than 10 Strings.

Sorry for any misunderstandings.

Why it has this behavior?

*Client*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JSimpleClient {
 Socket sock;
 Scanner eingabe;
 String[] sat = new String[10];
 BufferedWriter bw;
 ObjectInputStream stream;
 String s;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
  JSimpleClient ct = new JSimpleClient();
  ct.jetzt();
 }
 public void jetzt() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  try {
   sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1000);
   System.out.print("Bitte etwas eingeben:");
   eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = eingabe.nextLine();
   bw = new BufferedWriter(new   OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
   bw.write(input);
   bw.newLine();
   bw.flush();

   stream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
   sat = (String[]) stream.readObject();
   for(String d : sat) {
    s = d;
    System.out.println(s);
   }
  } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)   {System.out.println("BufferOverFlow ?!");}
    catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
 }
}
```

*Server*

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JsimpleServer {
 String[] sa = {"okay","okay","okay","okay","okay","okay","okay"
        ,"okay","okay","okay","okay","okay","okay","okay","okay","okay"};

 BufferedReader reader;
 ObjectOutputStream oos;
 ServerSocket ss;
 Socket socket1;
 boolean swi = true;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  JsimpleServer jss = new JsimpleServer(); 
  jss.startApp();
 }

 private void startApp() {
  try {
   ss = new ServerSocket(1000);
   while(swi) {
    socket1 = ss.accept();
    System.out.println("Server is started !");
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(sa);

    reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());

    oos.close();
       }
    } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println("Couldn`t connect !");
        Logger.getLogger(JsimpleServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
    }
}
```

Comment: To get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, you'd need to be doing something with an array, or a string, and indexes. As far as I can see, you're not.

Comment: I use the sa[] with 16 Strings and sat[] with 10 limitation , arrays.Maybe you may point out where in the code it should be manipulated. Thanks

Comment: 'Forcing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException?' has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:sockets].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
>   dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
>   (§4.3.2).

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html).

On this line:

```
sat = (String[]) stream.readObject();
```

you are assigning to `sat` a **new** array with length 16. A simplified version of what you do:

```
static void test1() throws Exception {

    String sat[] = new String[10];
    //server
    String[] sa = {"okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay"
        , "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay", "okay"};

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(sa);
    System.out.println(sat.length);//->10
    //client
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    sat = (String[]) is.readObject();//->sat points to another array now
    System.out.println(sat.length);//->16

  }
```

This will output 10 and 16 but won't throw an exception as you maybe expect.

Here is sample code that will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
static void test() {

    String words[] = new String[]{"Hello", "beautiful", "world!"};

    for (int idx = 0; idx <= words.length; idx++) {
      System.out.println(words[idx]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe not quite good as I thought, but I changed the for-loop and added a new String array. And now it creates the exception. Maybe to use another streams would be better.

Thank you.

```
for(int i = 0; sat.length > i; i++) {
 s = sat[i];
 sat2[i] = s;
 System.out.println("Array sat: " + sat.length);
 System.out.println("Array sat2: " + sat2.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when you try to use an invalid index.

A simple

```
int [] array = { 0 } ;
array[1]++;
```

Should do.